# Ubuntu Touch install for Galaxy Tab 2 tablet

Tags: installation, ubuntu-touch, tablet

### I am trying to install Ubuntu Touch on my Galaxy Tab 2 tablet.

But for 'recover mode', the options I get are not same options as mentioned in the instructions. I get the following options:

- Reboot now
- Apply update from SDcard
- Wipe data/factory reset
- Wipe cache partition
- Apply update from cache

**What should I do now?**

Comment: Please clarify: *Galaxy Tab2* (**7.0** or **10.1**) and (**WiFi** or **WiFi + 3G**) model? eg. P3100, P3110, P5100, P5110.

Comment: What instructions are you following?

Answer (score 0):

I am also trying to do this. I was able to get farther than you have gotten (with a little trial and error) until I got stuck and asked a question [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/359163/installing-ubuntu-touch-on-a-samsung-galaxy-tab-2-p3113/). To get past the step that you are on (correct me if I don't understand the problem), I rooted my tablet (are you past that step?) and installed the app "ClockworkMod ROM Manager" (or something like that). It replaced the default menu that appears when you hold the volume up key (which is what you are currently in, right?) with one with the correct options to let me install from a zip file on my SD card (and back up the tablet). I downloaded the two images that I needed and was able to successfully install them (up to the point where Touch doesn't work... as detailed in my above link).

If you get past this and get to the point where you boot it, I would love to know if it works! As I am having a similar issue, knowing that it works for someone else would narrow down my problem.

P.s. I don't know why I put so many parenthesis in my post, I guess I am just in the mood for parenthesis today...