# Installing Ubuntu Touch on a Samsung Galaxy Tab 2 (p3113)

Tags: ubuntu-touch, android, tablet

I have a Galaxy tab (p3113). I have been trying for some time now to get the developer preview of Ubuntu Touch installed on it. I followed the instructions on the 3rd-party maintainer's page for my tablet model on the Touch install page. I got to the point where I supposedly boot it up and it works, but it just stays at a blank (backlit) screen, until I restart it. I have tried older builds of touch from the time that the image was last updated (4/4), but it just does the same thing. Are there known issues with this device-specific file? Or is there an official installer now?

I don't really understand why it still doesn't work even after using the build from the last known working time; is there anything in the instructions that I could have done wrong? Sorry that I haven't provided much detailed info, if there is specific information that I need to provide I can find it.